# Length of a toroidal helix

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differential-geometry

For the toroidal helix defined by

```
$Assumptions = {r > 0, R > 0, n \[Element] Integers, n > 0, t >= 0, t <= 2*Pi}
x[t_] := (R + r Cos[n t])*Cos[t]
y[t_] := (R + r Cos[n t])*Sin[t]
z[t_] := r Sin[n t]
```

the differential arc-length is:

```
l[t_] := FullSimplify[Sqrt[D[x[t], t]^2 + D[y[t], t]^2 + D[z[t], t]^2]]
```

and the arc-length becomes:

```
L = Integrate[l[t], t]
```

Unfortunately, when calculating the length over 1 period:

```
L /. t -> 0
FullSimplify[L /. t -> 2 Pi]
```

We get the output 0 for both evaluations. This is because Mathematica introduces some kind of modulo equivalence when integrating. This can be seen by plotting an example arc-length curve:

```
rule = {R -> 6, r -> 2, n -> 5}
Plot[L /. rule, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Still, by noticing that the integrand is $2\pi/ n$ periodic, we can try to extract the solution by finding the difference between, say:

```
FullSimplify[Limit[L, t -> Pi/n, Direction -> "FromBelow"]]
FullSimplify[Limit[L, t -> Pi/n, Direction -> "FromAbove"]]
```

and multiplying it by $n$. This is taking too long for my computer and I can't seem to make any progress. **Is there a way to solve this problem in the form presented? Would analytical work help to get rid of this modulo equivalence (for example the Weierstrass substitution and further manipulations)?**

Comment: I can't get any results from your Integrate expression in a reasonable time. How long did you have to wait? What does the result look like? Finally, the numerical calculation seems to work fine: `Plot[NIntegrate[l[t] /. rule, {t, 0, tmax}], {tmax, 0, 2 Pi}]` giving a positive, almost linearly increasing value throughout.

Comment: x,y,z are periodic functions of t. Therefore, your definition for the arc length will also be periodic. You have to introduce aperiodicity "by hand"

Comment: @MarcoB I waited 30 seconds. Checked with Timing[]

Comment: I get the integral in terms of a complex expression containing arcsinh[g(t)] and complex square roots which because they're  multivalued, Matheamtica cannot (continuously) integrate across the branch cuts producing the jump-discontinuity exhibited in your plot. I suspect if we replaced these  with analytically-continuous versions, we could then use the resulting antiderivative to evaluate the definite integral. Might be an interesting project.   Would be tough though.

Comment: @josh This makes sense. I will try to manually manipulate the integral to hopefully get some more insight. In the meanwhile, I still do not know why Mathematica is not able to evaluate the limits at the end of the question.

Comment: @Michal Kuczynski:  Sorry I made a mistake above:  It's not branch cuts in the antiderivative but rather singular points due to the presence of several terms of the form $$\sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{33}{41}-\frac{10 i}{41}} \tan \left(\frac{5 t}{2}\right)\right)$$  with singular points equal to $5t/2=\pi/2+n \pi$ in the interval (0<t<2 Pi).  Not sure how to interpret antiderivative returned by Mathematica in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing integration with the rule-based integrator 'Rubi' https://rulebasedintegration.org/, you get an analytical solution.

'Rubi' gives an antiderivative with ArcTan[ ... Tan[...]], where it is easier to find a continuation over the branch cuts.

Doing it here for given paramters.

```
$Assumptions = {r > 0, R > 0, n \[Element] Integers, n > 0, t >= 0};
x[t_] = (R + r Cos[n t])*Cos[t];
y[t_] = (R + r Cos[n t])*Sin[t];
z[t_] = r Sin[n t];

rule0 = {R -> 6, r -> 2, n -> 5};

igd0 = FullSimplify[Sqrt[D[x[t], t]^2 + D[y[t], t]^2 + D[z[t], t]^2]]

igd = igd0 /. rule0

(*   Sqrt[276 + 48 Cos[5 t] + 4 Cos[10 t]]/Sqrt[2]   *)

(* rint[t_] = Int[igd, t]  Rubi integration: Get   *)

rint[t_] = 
  6/5 ArcTan[(2 Tan[(5 t)/2])/Sqrt[
     41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4]] + 
   2/5 Cos[(5 t)/2] Sin[(5 t)/2] Sqrt[
    41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4] - (
   2 Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2] Sqrt[
    41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4])/(
   5 (41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2)) + (2 1189^(1/4)
       EllipticE[2 ArcTan[(29/41)^(1/4) Tan[(5 t)/2]], (
       1189 - 33 Sqrt[1189])/
       2378] (41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2) Sqrt[(
      41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 
       29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4)/(41 + 
        Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2)^2])/(5 Sqrt[
      41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4]) - (12 1189^(1/4)
       EllipticF[2 ArcTan[(29/41)^(1/4) Tan[(5 t)/2]], (
       1189 - 33 Sqrt[1189])/
       2378] (41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2) Sqrt[(
      41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 
       29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4)/(41 + 
        Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2)^2])/(5 (41 - Sqrt[1189]) Sqrt[
      41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4]) - (29^(
      1/4) (41 - Sqrt[1189]) EllipticF[
       2 ArcTan[(29/41)^(1/4) Tan[(5 t)/2]], (1189 - 33 Sqrt[1189])/
       2378] (41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2) Sqrt[(
      41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 
       29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4)/(41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2)^2])/(5 41^(
      3/4) Sqrt[41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4]) + (6 41^(
      1/4) (29 + Sqrt[1189]) EllipticPi[(1189 - 35 Sqrt[1189])/2378, 
       2 ArcTan[(29/41)^(1/4) Tan[(5 t)/2]], (1189 - 33 Sqrt[1189])/
       2378] (41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2) Sqrt[(
      41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 
       29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4)/(41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2)^2])/(5 29^(
      3/4) (41 - Sqrt[1189]) Sqrt[
      41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4]);

Plot[rint[t], {t, 0, 5}]

srint[t_] = 
 rint[t] // PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]] & // 
  Simplify[#, Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]] &
```

(-1)^Floor[...] terms are ==1 except some singular points, which is not relevant. Set them to 1 later.

```
Plot[(-1)^
 Floor[(\[Pi] + 2 Arg[41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2] - 
   Arg[41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4])/(2 \[Pi])], {t, 0,
   5}]

Reduce[(-1)^
   Floor[(\[Pi] + 2 Arg[41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2] - 
     Arg[41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4])/(2 \[Pi])] == 
   1 && 0 < t < 5, t]

(*   0 < t < \[Pi]/5 || \[Pi]/5 < t < (3 \[Pi])/5 || (3 \[Pi])/5 < 
  t < \[Pi] || \[Pi] < t < (7 \[Pi])/5 || (7 \[Pi])/5 < t < 5   *)
```

Continuation rule for `ArcTan[aa_ Tan[bb_]]` terms is

```
ruleArcTan = 
 ArcTan[aa_ Tan[bb_]] -> 
  ArcTan[aa Tan[bb]] + bb - 2 ArcTan[Cot[bb] (-1 + Sqrt[Sec[bb]^2])]

Plot[Evaluate[
  bb - 2 ArcTan[Cot[bb] (-1 + Sqrt[Sec[bb]^2])] /. bb -> 5/2 t], {t, 
  0, 5}]

Plot[ArcTan[2 Tan[5/2 t]], {t, 0, 5}]

Plot[Evaluate[ArcTan[2 Tan[5/2 t]] /. ruleArcTan], {t, 0, 5}]
```

First term of srint[t] has to be excluded form ArcTan transformation, would give wrong result.

```
(sr3 = List @@ (srint[t] /. (-1)^
         Floor[(\[Pi] + 2 Arg[41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2] - 
           Arg[41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4])/(
          2 \[Pi])] -> 1 // Expand)) // TableForm;

Plot[#, {t, 0, 5}] & /@ sr3
```

Get analytical integral int[t] and compare with numerical integration

```
nint[tmax_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[igd, {t, 0, tmax}]

int[t_] = 
 sr3[[1]] + (Total@sr3[[2 ;; Length[sr3]]] /. ruleArcTan) // 
  Simplify[#, Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]] &

(*   1/290 (348 ArcTan[(2 Tan[(5 t)/2])/Sqrt[
     41 + 66 Tan[(5 t)/2]^2 + 29 Tan[(5 t)/2]^4]] + 
   116 1189^(1/4)
     EllipticE[
     5 t - 4 ArcTan[Cot[(5 t)/2] (-1 + Sqrt[Sec[(5 t)/2]^2])] + 
      2 ArcTan[(29/41)^(1/4) Tan[(5 t)/2]], 
     1/2 - 33/(2 Sqrt[1189])] - 
   116 1189^(1/4)
     EllipticF[
     5 t - 4 ArcTan[Cot[(5 t)/2] (-1 + Sqrt[Sec[(5 t)/2]^2])] + 
      2 ArcTan[(29/41)^(1/4) Tan[(5 t)/2]], 
     1/2 - 33/(2 Sqrt[1189])] - (1/(-41 + Sqrt[1189]))
   348 1189^(1/4)
     EllipticPi[1/2 - 35/(2 Sqrt[1189]), 
     5 t - 4 ArcTan[Cot[(5 t)/2] (-1 + Sqrt[Sec[(5 t)/2]^2])] + 
      2 ArcTan[(29/41)^(1/4) Tan[(5 t)/2]], 
     1/2 - 33/(2 Sqrt[1189])] - (1/(-41 + Sqrt[1189]))
   12 1189^(3/4)
     EllipticPi[1/2 - 35/(2 Sqrt[1189]), 
     5 t - 4 ArcTan[Cot[(5 t)/2] (-1 + Sqrt[Sec[(5 t)/2]^2])] + 
      2 ArcTan[(29/41)^(1/4) Tan[(5 t)/2]], 
     1/2 - 33/(2 Sqrt[1189])] + 
   29 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(69 + 12 Cos[5 t] + Cos[10 t]) Sec[(5 t)/2]^4]
     Sin[5 t] - (
   58 Sqrt[2378] Sqrt[(69 + 12 Cos[5 t] + Cos[10 t]) Sec[(5 t)/2]^4]
     Tan[(5 t)/2])/(41 + Sqrt[1189] Tan[(5 t)/2]^2))   *)

Limit[int[t], t -> 0, Direction -> -1]   (*   0   *)

Plot[{nint[t], int[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[.3], Thickness[.02], Red}, Black}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[nint[t] - int[t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
 PlotRange -> 10^-8, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

Comment: This is a masterpiece. However, `NIntegrate` is simpler and more convenient.

Comment: @Akku14:  Outstanding!  Beautiful example extending the Fundamendal Theorem of Calculus to multi-valued antiderivatives via  analytic continuation.  The concept should become a standard addendum to this important theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Since Mathematica will ignore some constant for everywhere when we integral a function, so Newton-Leibniz formula not always work.

```
Clear[n, R, r, x, y, z];
n = 5;
R = 2;
r = 1;
x[t_] = (R + r Cos[n t])*Cos[t];
y[t_] = (R + r Cos[n t])*Sin[t];
z[t_] = r Sin[n t];
ArcLength[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, N[0], N[2 π]}]
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}];
DiscretizeGraphics[plot] // ArcLength
NIntegrate[D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, t] // Norm, {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

> `34.0869` `34.0784` `34.0869`
> [image]

Comment: It looks like the OP needs to confirm if an analytic form for the arclength function is really necessary, or if a numerical evaluation suffices.

Comment: An exact formula  `2 *Pi*n *Sqrt[R^2/n^2 + r^2]` is claimed [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/arc-length-around-helical-torus.211201/). Unfortunately, the one is in discordance with numerical results.

Comment: @J. M. a numerical evaluation is unfortunately not sufficient. Explicit results would be of importance in the field of plasma confinement.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you, I have seen this and was puzzled. It must be an approximation.

Answer (score 2):

This is the result obtained from Mathematica with general parameters following tedious simplification and taking care of the ArcTan jumps with the Floor function (still quite messy...):

```
r = 2; R = 6; n = 5; Plot[{NIntegrate[
Sqrt[r^2 + 2*n^2*r^2 + 2*R^2 + 4*r*R*Cos[n*tt] + r^2*Cos[2*n*tt]]/
Sqrt[2], {tt, 0, t}], 
  (1/
 n)*((Sqrt[I*r + n*r + I*R]*Sqrt[I*r + n*r + I*R]*
    Sqrt[(-I)*r + n*r + I*R]*
    EllipticF[
     ArcTan[(Sqrt[(-I)*r + n*r + I*R]*Tan[(n*t)/2])/
        Sqrt[I*r + n*r + I*R]] + 
      Pi*(1 + Floor[(n*t)/(2*Pi) - 1/2]), 
              -((4*I*n*r^2)/((-I + n)^2*r^2 + R^2))])/
  Sqrt[(-I)*r + n*r - I*R] - (2*I*
    R*(Sqrt[I*r + n*r + I*R]*Sqrt[I*r + n*r + I*R])*
    EllipticPi[(2*r)/((1 + I*n)*r - R), 
              
     ArcTan[(Sqrt[(-I)*r + n*r + I*R]*Tan[(n*t)/2])/
        Sqrt[I*r + n*r + I*R]] + 
      Pi*(1 + Floor[(n*t)/(2*Pi) - 1/2]), -((4*I*n*
          r^2)/((-I + n)^2*r^2 + R^2))])/(Sqrt[(-I)*r + n*r + 
      I*R]*Sqrt[(-I)*r + n*r - I*R]) + 
       
 Sqrt[(-I)*r + n*r - I*R]*Sqrt[(-I)*r + n*r + I*R]*
  EllipticE[
   ArcTan[(Sqrt[(-I)*r + n*r + I*R]*Tan[(n*t)/2])/
      Sqrt[I*r + n*r + I*R]] + Pi*(1 + Floor[(n*t)/(2*Pi) - 1/2]), 
           -((4*I*n*r^2)/((-I + n)^2*r^2 + R^2))] + (Sqrt[
      r^2 + 2*n^2*r^2 + 2*R^2 + 4*r*R*Cos[n*t] + r^2*Cos[2*n*t]]/
     Sqrt[2] - (Sqrt[
        n*r - I*R - I*r*Cos[n*t]]*((-I)*r + n*r + I*R))/
     Sqrt[n*r + I*R + I*r*Cos[n*t]])*
         Tan[(n*t)/2])}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 300, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]
```

[image]

Edit:
Compare this with the arc length of a linear helix (green dots)

```
Sqrt[1 + n^2*r^2]*t
```

for n=5:
[image]

and n=15:
[image]

The simple linear curve approaches the complex elliptic expression for higher n.